# C++ -- fastest way to set an array of floats to the same value

Tags: c++

I naively thought I could use memset for this, but apparently memset is only for chars. Is there a memset-type thing that will work on an array of floats? Or is simple iteration the fastest way to copy a single value to every spot in an array?

Comment: If you're setting the floats to zero then memset does work (assuming the standard IEEE 754 float representation). You have to get the casts and array size calculation right though.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I won't speak to what code runs the fastest. You should compare them yourself, in the intended environment.

But, here are two readable, maintainable, correct solutions.

```
std::fill(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 3.14);
```

Or, if you have a dynamic array:

```
std::fill(array, array+size, 3.14);
```

Comment: +1, I need to become more familiar with the standard library's algorithms.

Comment: Or, `std::fill_n(array, size, 3.14);`

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend `std::fill`.

```
std::fill(
    floatArray + 0, floatArray + LENGTH
  , newValue
);
```

The compiler knows what you are trying to do here, and decent implementations can provide appropiate optimizations.

Comment: If your compiler supports the current version of C++ (C++11) you can use the std::begin() and std::end() functions instead of trying to manually calculate the end of the array. `fill(begin(floatArray),end(floatArray),newValue)`

Comment: @bames53: Thats assuming its a static array.

Comment: well if it's a dynamic array then it's a std::vector, right? ;)

Answer (score 4):

The standard way is:

```
std::fill(float_array, float_array + array_size, 0.0f);
```

I suspect you could beat this standard facility without non-standard methods.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to loop through and set all the values to 0 (which is what `memset` does anyway):

```
// this is a generic function to set all the elements of an array of any type (that has a public assignment operator and copy constructor) to a specific value
template<typename T>
void setarray(T* array, const T val, unsigned int array_size) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
        array[i] = val;
}

float* floatArray = new float[x];

setarray(floatArray, 0, x);
```

If the particular value you want to set all the elements of the array to happens to be 0 and you are using a compile time array, you can use an initialiser list:

```
float myArray[CONSTANT] = {}; // all values are 0
```

Comment: You don't need to write your own function for this. std::fill works just fine.

Comment: @bames53 hence my comment on Rob's answer

Comment: Ah, that wasn't there when I read his post. Rob's answer has gone from 0 to 10 votes pretty quickly!

Answer (score 1):

There is `memfill` function 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man3/memfill.3pub.html

in  publib nonstandard library. It can be used in ubuntu.

```
 #include <publib.h>

   float a=4.4;
   memfill(buf_ptr, buf_size, &a, sizeof(float) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads and initialize sub-ranges with separate threads.

Comment: since memory write speed is the bottleneck, would that help at all? I have a feeling it will be slower (even without the overhead of creating the threads)

Answer (score -1):

If you have a multiple dimensional float array then you could do something like this:

```
float myMultiDimensionFloats[5][250];
float myfloats[250];

for(int i=0; i<250;i++)
    myfloats[i] = 3.14f; // the value you want to store in each float entry

for(int ii=0; ii<5; ii++)
    CopyMemory(myMultiDimensionFloats[ii], &myfloats, sizeof(myMultiDimensionFloats[ii]));
```

Or if you want to use the template from "Seth Carnegie" :

```
#define LEN(arr) ((int) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0]))
float myMultiDimensionFloats[5][250];
setarray(myMultiDimensionFloats[0], 3.14f, LEN(myMultiDimensionFloats) * LEN(myMultiDimensionFloats[0]));
```

Comment: perhaps you could make a comment on why you downvote - otherwise how can I improve this post ?